# Connection to Heroku app gets refused when my IP changes

Tags: node.js, heroku, ip, shopify

I've built a Node.js app which I'm hosting on Heroku.

The app is meant to be installed/used by Shopify stores (but hopefully that's irrelevant )

I built, installed and tested the app (not locally but form within an actual Shopify store) at home using my home internet connection there and everything is working fine.

Whenever, I try to access the installed app from a different location (i.e not using my home connection) I get an `ERR:Connection Refused`.

This is unrelated to any cookies/tokens  that could have been saved in my local machine because the problem that I get is that the request that goes out from the client (shop) to my Node.js server (Heroku) whenever I try to run my app, never reaches my server.

Heroku Support have yet to come up with and answer so I'm wondering whether anyone has had similar problems?

Here's what I've tried on the terminal and the responses I got (you can try it yourselves)

```
curl -I https://shopify-blox.herokuapp.com
```

returned :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to shopify-blox.herokuapp.com port 443: Connection refused
```

also :

```
dig shopify-blox.herokuapp.com
```

returned :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> shopify-blox.herokuapp.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 742
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;shopify-blox.herokuapp.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
shopify-blox.herokuapp.com. 300 IN CNAME us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com. 28 IN A 54.243.114.196

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.254#53(192.168.1.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 26 11:06:08 2015
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 92
```

By the way, trying to access other Heroku apps (hosted under the same Heroku account) using the same internet connection that I used for the above tests works just fine.

Comment: Do you have a link to the heroku app. We can try to ping it and see if its up for us. The heroku app should be accepting from any IP, so it sounds like the app might not be sending requests properly.

Comment: There is no IP restriction on heroku apps, so you should be able to access your app from anywhere.

Did you contact heroku via help.heroku.com? I'm monitoring our node queue and it's currently empty. A ticket number would be helpful if you have one.

Comment: Hi hunterloftis, the ticket # is 305995. I'm already in talks with support and they've been really quick with their responses but I'm afraid they're still trying to figure out what's happening themselves.

Comment: Hi hunterloftis, did you ever find my ticket? The issue  hasn't be resolved yet I'm afraid and it is really weird.